# why does type hinted spread operatored parameter works with no argument

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

Here is a function with type hinting and spread operated parameter.

```php
function setObjects(Object ...$objects)
{
   //do something
}
```

If I call this function without any parameters like this

```
setObjects();
```

It still works. Shouldn't the type hinting throw error at this point?
Why is this not an error?

Comment: its variadic (say it can take a variable amount of arguments [including none]), so that argument will always end up as an array ... the checking comes in if you actually pass arguments (then it will make sure they are of the type declared)